# Cancel UIGestureRecognizer when a button is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to cancel a `UIGestureRecognizer` when I tap on a button?

Comment: Why not? But make your question more clear

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel"? Be more specific/clear.

Answer (score 9):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    // test if our control subview is on-screen
    if([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            return NO; // ignore the touch
        }
    }
    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

Comment: This will not cancel the recognizer, just ignore the button touch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

return whateverYouWant;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can add it and remove, by this code.

```
-(IBAction) YourButtonAction {
  some code, that your button must to do
  self.yourButton removeGestureRecognizer: (yourRecognizer);
}
```